# не понимаю поведение for loop в js

Tags: javascript, for

Я создал лупу и сунул в нее уже обозначенное ранее значение, например `let row = 0, column = 0`,  но почему-то оно не работает как должно(по моему мнению) в моём первом примере, но если я обозначу значение `let row = 0 / column = 0` в саму лупу, то всё работает как надо (воторой пример) -_- Почему так происходит?

Вот сама лупа(не работающая как надо):

```js
let size = 8
let board = ""
let column = 0
let row = 0
for (; column < size; column++) {
  for (; row < size; row++) {
    if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
      board += " ";
    } else {
      board += "#";
    }
  }
  board += "\n";
}
console.log(board);
```

И вот пупа которая работает "как надо":

```js
let size = 8
let board = ""
for (let column = 0; column < size; column++) {
  for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
      board += " ";
    } else {
      board += "#";
    }
  }
  board += "\n";
}
console.log(board);
```

Comment: В первом примере перед внутренним циклом переменную row никто не обнуляет, вот и всё, let тут ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal так я же обозначил - "обнулил" значение row и column = 0, разве это не обнуление? Я просто давно читал что можно как-то использовать лупу без первого значения если оно было уже обозначено выше, т.е. ` let column = 0` и уже отталкиваться от этого. Или это не так работает?

Comment: Вы обнулили его всего один раз перед первой итерацией цикла, а когда внешний цикл выполняется второй раз, row никто не обнуляет и в нём остаётся значение size из прошлой итерации, следовательно внутренний цикл больше ни разу не выполняется

Comment: @andreymal АААА, понял теперь, спасибо большое!